# dnscrypt makes network unavailable

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, dns, dnscrypt-proxy

i'm using ubuntu 18.04 and i tried to install dnscrypt using this [tutorial](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/install-and-enable-dnscrypt-proxy-2-in.html)

but when i tried to connect to a website it always failed,
i tried to check the status of the dnscrypt service, and it shows error `[ERROR] Unable to retrieve server certificates` like this:

[image]

i tried to edit /etc/resolv.conf and change the nameserver to `127.0.2.1` but when i restarted the `NetworkManager`, the nameserver goes back to `127.0.0.53`

after that i tried to disable these two, but nothing changes

```
sudo systemctl disable dnscrypt-proxy.service && sudo systemctl disable dnscrypt-proxy-resolvconf.service
```

Comment: Can you provide the outputs of 1) `cat /etc/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.toml` 2) `sudo ss -lp 'sport = :domain'` (preferably when all GUI software are closed) 3) `lsattr /etc/resolv.conf` 4) `cat /lib/systemd/system/dnscrypt-proxy.socket` 5) `sudo systemctl status dnscrypt-proxy.socket`

Comment: Also it is normal that `/etc/resolv.conf` does not stick, you need to have the immutable bit on `resolv.conf` to prevent changes by NetworkManager. Depending on the output of the commands I wrote in the previous comment, I will provide a proper answer.